# How should I touch up my exterior door's paint after changing hardware?

Tags: doors, painting, paint

After installing some new locks and handles, I realized that the previous owners didn't have the entire door painted but rather it was only around the hardware. I have the paint color and paint type, but should I have this sprayed professionally or is there another way to get this painted by myself?

It looks like it is not primed as well, so I'm guessing I will need to prime this?

[image: Door not painted]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could buy a sprayer for about $100 or less; I think a painter will charge you at least that much to spray it.

A sprayer such as this [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074K1K3MB) or a wagner type airless sprayer should work Wagners are generally good for one or two uses unless you get a pro unit - ~$290.00 . I have had a couple of the Wagners , managed to get one to last through 4 rooms.

Here is how you can spray it.

- Remove the door by removing the Hinge Pins.
- Remove your hardware from the door.
- Stand your door in a way that you can spray it while holding the
  sprayer  horizontally - keeping the nozzle about 12 to 18 inches from
  the surface of the door.

Hold the spray nozzle straight towards the door and walk along the door and spray (start from the top and work your way down - in case you create a run - you can fix it (wipe it) and continue) - remember keep the nozzle straight - no flexing of the wrist.

Start spraying before you reach the door and finish spraying when you have passed the door.

Continue this process until the door is completely painted.

Let the door dry.

Reinstall the door hardware and the door. You might need a helper as putting the hinge pins back in and holding the door may be difficult - putting shims under the door to hold it up and in place while installing the pins-  will make it easier to do it alone.

The best ambient temperature fro spray painting like this is around 70 degrees, if it is 90 degrees - move your nozzle a little closer to the door - 12 inches instead of 18 as the paint will tend to dry faster, if it is colder the issue is that of adhesion, your paint may not stick so well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd get satisfactory results with an inexpensive foam mini-roller. Gently sand the edges of the existing paint to minimize their appearance, then load your roller and pre-roll it on some cardboard to lighten the load. Roll over the bare area, blending a bit with the surroundings.

To minimize stipple, apply several light coats, allowing it to dry between. With the embossed woodgrain texture and this approach I think you'll be happy.

Comment: With that being an exterior door - I think the op will end up with a mismatch in coloration - as the sunlight and oxidation of the outdoor environment has probably caused that paint to fade, but hey it is worth a shot if it works.$5 is better than $100 unless the $100 is coming your way..